# Unbound method error while calling static method

Tags: python, function, static-methods, python-2.4

I have a class with two methods in it, one static and another none static:

```
class Person(object):
    def getDetails(self):
        Person.change_something(self.name)

    @staticmethod
    def change_something(name):
        return name.upper()
```

When I create an instance of a class Person and call `person.getDetails()`, I am getting error that says  `unbound method change_something() must be called with Person instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`. Can anyone point me what wrong I am doing here?

Comment: that is not a complete, testable example (colon missing). please post your real code, but try to simplify it to the most simplest form which reproduces the problem (eg: here self.name can be replaces with: "test"). we need a code that we can copy-paste, includes object creation and call, everything.

Answer (score 3):

`staticmethod` is a descriptor. Descriptors only work on new-style classes.

```
class Person(object):
```

Comment: True but this might be Python 3 code, in which all classes are new-style by default.

Comment: I did this as well but, still I am getting the same error! By the way I am using Python 2.4!